# Is there a way to only show the first record in a Crystal Report that does not meet a specified condition?

Tags: crystal-reports

Say I have data formatted as follows in a Crystal Report:

```
Job: 1

Asm      Opr      LbrQty
0        10       0.0
0        10       60.0
0        10       60.0
0        20       65.0
0        30       0.0
0        30       20.0
0        30       40.0

Job: 2

Asm      Opr      LbrQty
0        10       60.0
0        10       60.0
0        10       75.0
0        20       0.0
0        20       165.0
0        30       0.0
0        30       20.0
0        30       40.0
0        40       60.0
1        10       60.0
1        10       60.0
1        10       75.0
1        20       0.0
1        20       165.0
1        30       0.0
1        30       20.0
1        40       0.0
1        40       60.0
```

I only want the report to show the first Opr within an Asm where LbrQty is NOT zero, as below:

```
Job: 1

Asm      Opr      LbrQty
0        10       60.0
0        20       65.0
0        30       20.0

Job: 2

Asm      Opr      LbrQty
0        10       60.0
0        20       165.0
0        30       20.0
0        40       60.0
1        10       60.0
1        20       165.0
1        30       20.0
1        40       60.0
```

I've attempted to use the following as my Supression Formula, which works for the most part, but still occasionally displays multiple records with the same Opr:

```
(
    Previous ({OprSeq}) = ({OprSeq}) and
    Previous ({JobNum}) = ({JobNum}) and
    Previous ({LaborQty}) <> 0
) or

(
    ({LaborQty}) = 0
)
```

How can I change my formula to give me the behavior I require?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below way:

Create a running total with following criteria:

1. In field to summairze take `lbrqty` and take `count` as summary option
2. In  evalute use option `formula` and write below code:

   {lbrqty}>0
3. In Reset use option `On change of field` `opr`

Now use this running total to supress.. Now in supress of the section write below code:

```
if {#RTotal1}=1
then false
else true
```

Comment: Aside from changing the formula to `({LaborQty}) = 0 or {#RTotal0} <> 1` this is exactly what I was looking for, thank you!